# Query replace and commenting out

Tags: auctex, regular-expressions

I want to comment out all environments say `myenv` in a tex-file. I can find them with the regexp:

`\\begin{myenv}\(.\|\n\).*?\\end{myenv}`

(instead of `\n` I had do type `C-q C-j`).

But what would be the correct regexp for replacing? How to reverse it, i.e. uncomment all environments `myenv`?

Comment: Can be done in emacs. But I wonder whether it would be better to use the [LaTeX-package "comment"](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment?lang=en) for this purpose. With this package you can set `\excludecomment{myenv}` in the document preamble. Your regexp is interesting in the aspect that you only allow one newline behind `\\begin{myenv}` and the backslash for the or-operator is missing. I would expect `\\begin{myenv}\(.\|n\)*\\end{myenv}` as regexp.

Comment: I just wanted to add that you have to type `C-q C-j` for the newline character `n` in my last comment. You have already mentioned that in your question.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to write a loop to find all `myenv` environments and applying `comment-region` to each match. Or apply `uncomment-region` to undo it. You should be able to use the same regexp for both cases. (Sorry, don't have the time to flesh this out to a proper answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I think, for what you are doing, the comment by Tobias provides a superior solution.  And  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex) gives quite a few options for commenting out chunks of code.  That said, I'll assume this is an issue with using emacs, rather than latex.

Make your entire regex match a group `\(regex\)`, then the regex to replace it will be similar to `\\iffalse \1 \\fi`.

An easier solution would be to write a keyboard macro that finds the begin\end environment commands and inserts the comment code there.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `re-search-forward` <kbd>RET</kbd>

MY_REGEXP  <kbd>RET</kbd>

followed by
 <kbd>M-x</kbd> `comment-dwim`  <kbd>RET</kbd>

;;;

`comment-dwim` is at <kbd>M-;</kbd>

After `re-search-forward` the region should be visible.

If not  <kbd>C-x</kbd>  <kbd>C-x</kbd> resp.  <kbd>M-x</kbd>`exchange-point-and-mark`<kbd>RET</kbd>